# Footnote not coming on the page

Tags: footnotes, ieeetran

Please find the code as below:

```
             \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
     \makeatother
     \usepackage{abstract}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
      \theoremstyle{definition}
      \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
 \begin{document}
 \title{aa}
  \author{ABCD}% <-this % stops a space
 \twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
 \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    \saythanks{ \small
      ABCD. \footnote{abcd}}
   \begin{abstract} 
  In this paper,  
  \end{abstract}
       ]
       \IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle
            \end{document}
```

I want a footnote showing the author affiliation. Although I have given the command \footnote{abcd}, but I am not able to get the footnote at the bottom of page. How can I get the footnote?

Answer (score 1):

As per the `IEEE` standard format, author's affiliations should be placed under the author's names, and the the format is:

```
 \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
     \makeatother
     \usepackage{abstract}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
      \theoremstyle{definition}
      \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
 \begin{document}
 \title{aa}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, Homer Simpson\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, James K
irk\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}, Montgomery Scott\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and Eldon Tyrell\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Ele
ctrical and Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology, Atlanta, Georgia 30
332--0250\\
Email: mshell@ece.gatech.edu}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Twentieth Cen
tury Fox, Springfield, USA\\
Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}Starfleet Aca
demy, San Francisco, California 96678-2391\\
Telephone: (800) 555--1212, Fax: (888) 555--1212}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}Tyrell Inc.,
123 Replicant Street, Los Angeles, California 90210
--4321}}
    \maketitle
   \begin{abstract} 
  In this paper,  
  \end{abstract}
       \IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle
            \end{document}
```

For better understanding, please refer the documentation about `IEEE`, `IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf`, page number `5`

Comment: I understand the IEEE format, however this is a self customized format for a different journal, which does not have its own format. So, it requires footnote at the bottom for the author name to show the current affiliation of the author.

Comment: @ShiS Oops...sorry, I thought that you are asking this requirement for standard `IEEE` format, that's why suggested like that, shall I remove my answer?

Comment: No, please. Keep the answer